# How to open exact image in bootstrap modal after clicking on image in owl carousel?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm using a Owl Carousel in a Bootstrap project. I want that when I click on a image of the carousel, the modal that is opening, has to show me the exact image (bigger) that I have clicked before, and not the first of the carousel.

Can someone help me, please?

I made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/njq4btpg/)

HTML

```
<div class="container GListFullWidth">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        <!-- owl-carousel -->
        <div id="owl-onpage">
            <div class="item"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GListModalGallery"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/500/sports/6/" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GListModalGallery"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/7/" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GListModalGallery"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/550/sports/8/" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GListModalGallery"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/600/sports/9/" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GListModalGallery"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/500/sports/6/" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GListModalGallery"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/7/" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GListModalGallery"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/550/sports/8/" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GListModalGallery"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/600/sports/9/" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /owl-carousel -->

        <span class="caption text-muted">A Chinese tale tells of some men sent to harm a young girl who, upon seeing her beauty, become her protectors rather than her violators.</span>

        <!-- modalGallery -->
        <div class="modal" id="GListModalGallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="GListModalGalleryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="owl-modal">
                            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/500/sports/6/" /></div>
                            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/7/" /></div>
                            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/550/sports/8/" /></div>
                            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/600/sports/9/" /></div>
                            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/500/sports/6/" /></div>
                            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/7/" /></div>
                            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/550/sports/8/" /></div>
                            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/600/sports/9/" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /modalGallery -->

    </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
</div><!-- /row -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to clean up your HTML and erase everything inside the div which ID is `owl-modal`. Then, you have to attach an event when user clicks on links into div which class is `item`.

You do everything into the document ready.

1. Initialyze the main carousel

   ```
   var owl = $("#owl-onpage");
   owl.owlCarousel({
       itemsCustom : [
           [0, 2],
           [979, 4]
       ],
       navigation : true,
       pagination: false,
       itemsScaleUp: true,
       addClassActive: true,
       navigationText: [
           "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
           "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"
       ],
   });
   ```
2. Add an event when user clicks on item picture

   ```
   $('#owl-onpage .item a').on('click', function() {});
   ```
3. Get the current item user clicked and insert it with into the `modal-body` div

   ```
   var theSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
   var owlModal = $('#owl-modal');
   owlModal.empty();
   var item = $('<div>', {'class' : 'item'}).appendTo(owlModal);
   $('<img>', {'src' : theSrc}).appendTo(item);
   ```
4. As the modal will learn the HTML item, you have to empty it each time. And we must also tell it to add additional images (ie all except the one the user clicked)

   ```
   // Add others images
   $('#owl-onpage .item a').each(function (i,e) {
       var otherSrc = $(e).find('img').attr('src');
       var item = $('<div>', {'class' : 'item'}).appendTo(owlModal);
       $('<img>', {'src' : otherSrc}).appendTo(item);
   });
   ```
5. Call the new carousel inside the modal

   ```
   // Call the carousel after clicked on 'a'
   owlModal.owlCarousel({
       singleItem:true,
       navigation : true,
       pagination: false,
       navigationText: [
           "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
           "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"
       ],
   });
   ```
6. Then, allowing the removal of modal when the carousel closes or if the `close button` is clicked.

   ```
   $('#GListModalGallery').unbind().on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
       owlModal.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
   });
   ```

Please note that I've add **`unbind()`** to remove events attached to the modal(s).

FINAL [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xck7ks1/)

Comment: @ferocesalatino Final comment. I will update my post. Success